# What is the shape of a rain water drop and how it forms?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag, surface-tension

What is the shape of a rain water drop and how it forms? 
When tried to figure that out using surface tension, water drop becomes unnatural. Lower part has a smaller radius and upper part has a larger one.

For upper part,
P1 - Patm = 2T/R1

For lower part,
P2 - Patm = 2T/R2

But, P2 = P1 + hdg

So R1>R2

T = surface tension of water
Patm = pressure of atmosphere 
h = length of the water drop
d = density of water
R1 = radius of the upper part
R2 = radius of the lower part
g is gravitational acceleration

But we see inverse type of water drops in natural. What is the real physics behind this?